# Find a character in a string from a given integer?

Tags: c++, string

I am currently working on a program that prompts the user to input their favorite color, and then asks them to give them a position of a character within the given color. The program will then take that given number and find the character. (ie, input Yellow as the color, and the put 2 as your character. The program should then display the character at that position is "l"). I have the beginning down, when it asks you the color and character position, but am struggling to convert that given into a letter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    //begin by asking user what their favorite color is

    string favColor;

    cout << "Input your favorite color: ";

    //store it as a variable
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    cin >> favColor;

    //next, ask the user what character they would like to display
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    int displayCharacter;

    cout << "Which character would you like to display: ";

    //store it as another variable
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    cin >> displayCharacter;

    //with the character saved as an int, now have program 
    //determine which character is in the given city
    //------------------------------------------------------------


    cout << "\n";
    cout << "The user input: " << favColor << "\n";

    cout << "The Character at position " << displayCharacter << " is: " <<  << endl;
```

Comment: `favColor[displayCharacter]` ?  (assuming the index is valid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In update version I used `std::string::at`, because you can ensure safer and more robust code by handling potential errors caused by accessing characters beyond the string's length!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string favColor;
    cout << "Input your favorite color: ";
    cin >> favColor;

    int displayCharacter;
    cout << "Which character would you like to display: ";
    cin >> displayCharacter;

    char character = favColor.at(displayCharacter);
    cout << "The Character at position " << displayCharacter << " is: " << character << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Input your favorite color: Yellow
Which character would you like to display: 2
The Character at position 2 is: l
```

Comment: The provided code fails to display the character 'l' when displayCharacter is set to 2.
It can be either char character = favColor[displayCharacter + 1], setting the first character to 1 (instead of 0), or simply favColor[displayCharacter].

Comment: Additionally, please take note that input validation, as mentioned by Sofyan Mahmoud in his answer, should also be considered.

Comment: @Freeman "*using type casting*" - there is no type casting being demonstrated in this answer. The correct answer is: use `std::string::operator[]`

Comment: @Doku the requirement clearly demonstrates that `displayCharacter` would have to be 0-based, so `favColor[displayCharacter]` will suffice. But if the input were 1-based, then you would have to use `favColor[displayCharacter - 1]` instead of `favColor[displayCharacter + 1]` as you suggested.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thnx for your reply,I think it's better to use the `std::string::at` function instead of `operator[]` to access the character at the specified position,because this ensures that an out-of-range access is handled properly and throws an exception if necessary, plz correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Freeman only if the code doesn't validate the position beforehand, otherwise the `at()` becomes redundant

Answer (score 3):

String is an array of character, so you can easily use random access to access the character with specific position(index). You code must be like that

```cpp
cout << "The Character at position " << displayCharacter << " is: " << favColor[displayCharacter] << endl;
```

> Note: Firstly, you must validate the input number, you must make sure it's greater than or equal 0 and less than the length of the favColor.

Comment: I up-voted this answer for two reasons. 1. Completeness: it includes the needed info about `operator[]` _and_ the requirement to validate the subscript. 2. It gives useful information to a student _without coding his homework assignment for him_.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [subscript operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at). With it you can access each `char` in the `std::string` with its position. It is usually used with arrays/pointers if you already know them, but it is overloaded for many containers in the STL such as the [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

You can use it like this:

```
std::string someText{"Hello, World!"};
std::cout << someText[2] << std::endl;    // this will print the char 'l'
```